# Derivative of dot product of Residual Sum Square in matrix notation

Tags: derivatives, regression, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I am trying to derive the following expression w.r.t. $\beta$:

\begin{equation}
RSS(\beta) = (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X} \beta)^T (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X} \beta)
\end{equation}

I know that the derivation of the dot product is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}(\mathbf{r}(x) \cdot \mathbf{s}(x)) = \mathbf{r'}(x) \cdot \mathbf{s}(x) + \mathbf{r}(x) \cdot \mathbf{s'}(x)
\end{equation}

but I am unable to understand how to differentiate when mixing transposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to expand the brackets first
\begin{align}
\mbox{RSS}(b) =& (y-Xb)'(y-Xb) = y'y - y'Xb-b'X'y+b'X'Xb\\
        =& y'y-2b'X'y+b'X'Xb
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\mbox{RSS}(\hat{b}) = -2X'y+2X'X\hat{b} = 0
\end{align}
by rearranging the equation you get
$$
X'X\hat{b}=X'y.
$$
Assuming no (complete) multicolinearity present, then $\exists \,\,(X'X)^{-1} $,
$$
\hat{b}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y,
$$
that is the OLS estimator of $b$.

Comment: Perfect, there is only one missing transpose operator in the last item of the first line: $b'XXb$ must be $b'X'Xb$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Edited.